# Pasar un objeto dentro de un include sin llamarlo con 'global $var'

Tags: php, poo, php7

Llevo unas horas en esto.

Estoy intentando pasar el objeto $objeto dentro del include sin tener que declararlo en cada archivo como en este ejemplo:

**index.php:**

```
include('uno.php');
$objeto = new uno(); // Este objeto quiero pasar al include.
include('dos.php');
```

**uno.php:**

```
class uno {
   function nada(){
      echo 'Nada';
   }
}
```

**dos.php**

```
global $objeto; // Este es el objeto que quiero pasar automáticamente, sin declararlo aquí
$objeto->nada();
```

Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: La duda sería ¿por que haces la instancia en ese archivo donde tienes esos 2 include?

Comment: @BetaM la verdad no es necesario hacer la instancia ahí, es para el ejemplo, si la hago en otra parte, ¿cambiaría el resultado?

Comment: puedes hacerlo si usas clases...

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Por qué si `$objeto`  parece que debería ser declarado en `dos.php` no lo declaras allí? ¿Qué justifica que tengas que pasarlo desde fuera del lugar donde parece que debería estar? Y, si `$objeto`  es algo que se necesita en `dos.php` para operar con él, entonces, si `dos.php`  es una clase simplemente tendrías que pasárselo en el constructor o método que trabajará con él. Y si `$objeto` es algo independiente, entonces mételo en un archivo y haz include de ese archivo donde lo necesites.

Comment: O bien, podría ser un problema de herencia. Si `$objeto` es algo que debería heredar de una clase que habría en `dos.php`, tendrías que resolverlo con la herencia. O, si `uno` y `dos` se relacionan, también la mejor solución sería la herencia... El problema de este tipo de preguntas es que tampoco muestra nada concreto: `uno, dos, objeto` no significan nada, son cosas genéricas. Si pones un ejemplo de la vida real sería más fácil entender el problema y aportar una solución óptima.